# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '18' in canjs

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-list

I am calling ajax function for getting data from model. I am trying to load the data in template but i cannot setting the attributes in can.list.
Here is my call:

```
this.domainModel.getDomains("domains", function (response, error) {
  if ('domains' in response) {
                   self.filteredList.attr("domains",list);
    } else {
        return error;
    }
})
```

It showing **Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '18'.** I search for this in google but I found the results for jquery. Is there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript `in` operator searches for a specific property name on a Javascript object.  That's what it does.

It doesn't search an array for a value in the array.  It doesn't search an object for a property with a given value.  Either of these uses would be coded differently.

It is not clear in your code what type of data structure you are trying to search for `18` in so we cannot really advise further how to solve your specific problem without more detail.

Here's how `in` works:

```
var test = {
    greeting: "hello",
    name: "john"
};

if ("greeting" in test) {
    console.log("found greeting property in test object");
}
```

Comment: I have json file which is having domains and I am calling it through can.ajax.  Is there any information needed to solve my problem?